# System load peaks on kubernetes master node on azure

Tags: azure, load, kubernetes

Does anyone know why we are experiencing on our kubernetes master node some system load peaks. I thought that the master node is not doing anything except monitoring our agent nodes.

Each time we have a system load peak of 1.8-2 on our dual-core machine, I see in the kube-controller-manager log that the master tries to start 3 things:

- controllermanager.go:373] Attempting to start disruption controller
- controllermanager.go:385] Attempting to start petset
- controllermanager.go:460] Attempting to start certificates

Our kubernetes version is 1.4.6 and is created via the azure portal. The system peaks can we see via datadog monitoring.

Comment: Is your azure service, free-tier or basic-tier?

Comment: it is an azure container service on a paid subscription

Comment: I think the issue might be with the service turns off every time the service is inactive. You may choose to activate `Always On` under Application Setting. That will keep it on, even if it unactive.

Comment: It is a container service, not an app service. So I don't have the Application Setting in a container service.